# What is the name of this type of website?

Tags: html, css, javascript

I'm not sure what stack exchange site I am supposed to ask this question in, but I will ask it here anyways.

This site has a particular style that I want to create on my own using HTML5, CSS3 and Javascript + jQuery. What is the name of this style of site, so I can find tutorials?

http://drinks.fm/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is basically a really, really, really abbreviated single-page website design. Most of the tutorials deal with single page parallax websites.

Because complex navigation systems reduce engagement, the idea is that by putting everything on one page you cut down on load time between sections. There are two key disadvantages to this style of site though.

1. You have to load all of your graphical assets up front, which can cause time to first byte issues since the server typically zips the assets ahead of a transfer. This can be mitigated by lazy loading anything below the fold, but this is a more advanced technique.
2. When Google spiders your site, they get one result, and may not index content below a certain point. In terms of a hub/authority structure, you risk sharply limiting your influence.

In 2012, UX sites were talking about [how scrolling is the new click](http://uxmovement.com/navigation/why-scrolling-is-the-new-click/). In 2014, we recognize that this design is also a pattern that tends to [violate back-button expectations](http://baymard.com/blog/back-button-expectations).

A final word of caution is this. Just as we know for an absolute fact that users don't typically click past the first image on a slider, we also know for a fact that in the design you're talking about most users won't scroll unless you give them a very good contextual reason to do so.

Technically, this isn't that hard of a design to pull off. In terms of usability, you're in dangerous territory. Do a lot of reading on sites like https://ux.stackexchange.com/ before jumping on top of this one.